# A long trigonometric expression

Tags: c++

I have the following expression in my C++ code:

```
theta1 = theta0 - (acos((pow(constlength_link1 + length, 2) + (pow(length_base_end, 2) - pow(length_link2, 2)))
     / (2 * length_base_end * (constlength_link1 + length)))) * 180 / M_PI;
```

I understand that such a code will be very difficult for anyone else to debug. Should I break it down using additional variables?

Are there any other better approaches?

**Edit**: Sorry about the lack of details:

I am trying to calculate sum of two angles `theta1` and `theta2`. These angles are being calculated by subtracting the `inverse of cosine` of an expression from a constant angle (`theta0 or 180`). The expression mentioned in the last line involves a division. The dividend is something like:

> (square of sum of two numbers) +/- (square of a number  - square of
>   another number)

The divisor is something like:

> (2 * a number * (sum of two numbers))

The function is as shown below:

```
float length_angle(float length = 0.0)
{
    float theta1, theta2;

    theta1 = theta0 - (acos((pow(constlength_link1 + length, 2) + (pow(length_base_end, 2) - pow(length_link2, 2)))
     / (2 * length_base_end * (constlength_link1 + length)))) * 180 / M_PI;

    theta2 = 180 - (acos((pow(constlength_link1 + length, 2) - (pow(length_base_end, 2) - pow(length_link2, 2)))
     / (2 * length_link2 * (constlength_link1 + length)))) * 180 / M_PI;

    return theta1 + theta2;
}
```

I would like to write this expression better so that someone else can read or debug the code if required.

Comment: Where does `theta0` come from? Is it a global variable? What does it represent?

Comment: Thats defined as  `constexpr float theta0 = 51.33`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am trying to calculate sum of two angles theta1 and theta2. These angles are being calculated by subtracting the inverse of cosine of an expression from a constant angle (theta0 or 180). The expression mentioned in the last line involves a division. The dividend is something like:
>
> (square of sum of two numbers) +/- (square of a number - square of another number)
>
> The divisor is something like:
>
> (2 * a number * (sum of two numbers))

Don't tell *us*, tell *the maintainer of your codebase!*

```
float length_angle(float length = 0)
{
    auto square = [](auto x) { return x*x; };

    auto dividend1 = square(constlength_link1 + length) + square(length_base_end) - square(length_link2);
    auto divisor1 = 2 * length_base_end * (constlength_link1 + length);

    float theta1 = theta0 - acos(dividend1 / divisor1) * 180 / M_PI;

    auto dividend2 = square(constlength_link1 + length) - square(length_base_end) + square(length_link2);
    auto divisor2 = 2 * length_link2 * (constlength_link1 + length);

    float theta2 = 180 - acos(dividend2 / divisor2) * 180 / M_PI;

    return theta1 + theta2;
}
```

Three optimizations I'd make to this code for better API design: First, don't use default function arguments. If I meant to write `length_angle(1)` but fat-fingered `length_angle()` instead, *give me an error!* If I meant to write `length_angle(0)`, trust me to write it. You're hurting more than you're helping when you try to save your caller that *one extra character* of typing.

Second, use radians. Radians are the right answer for trig in the same way that UTF-8 is the right answer for character encoding. Trust the past couple millennia of mathematicians when they tell you that angles should be measured in radians. This will save you some repetition here, and some unnecessary rounding errors as well.

Third, *optionally*, use `double`; it'll give you more accuracy and [be no slower — maybe even faster — than `float`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426165/is-using-double-faster-than-float) if you're targeting a normal desktop computer. Obviously if you're targeting a 32-bit microprocessor with hardware `float` and software-emulated `double`, don't use `double`. :)

In your real code, the above will be super readable because you'll be using real names for the variables instead of long placeholders like `constlength_link1`. You can also say `sqr` or `sq` instead of `square`. So:

```
double length_angle(double length)
{
    auto sq = [](auto x) { return x*x; };

    auto a1 = sq(L1 + length) + sq(L3) - sq(L2);
    auto b1 = 2 * L3 * (L1 + length);

    auto theta1 = theta0 - acos(a1 / b1);

    auto a2 = sq(L1 + length) + sq(L2) - sq(L3);
    auto b2 = 2 * L2 * (L1 + length);

    auto theta2 = M_PI - acos(a2 / b2);

    return theta1 + theta2;
}
```

Lastly, perhaps notice that `theta1 + theta2` is `theta0 + M_PI - (acos(a1/b1) + acos(a2/b2))`; and perhaps deal with the possibility of division-by-zero when `b1` or `b2` is zero. Or even factor out the repeated code, now that it's been made blatantly obvious by our renamings:

```
double length_angle(double length)
{
    auto sq = [](auto x) { return x*x; };

    auto f = [&](auto start, auto a, auto b) {
        auto y = sq(L1 + length) + sq(b) - sq(a);
        auto x = 2 * b * (L1 + length);
        return start - acos(y / x);
    };

    return f(theta0, L2, L3) + f(M_PI, L3, L2);
}
```

Comment: Aren't you abusing the use of auto? Declaring most of them that way makes it harder to determine what kind of values they should contain according to the coder's intent, which in turn makes it harder to debug.

Comment: Consider sprinkling `const` over the intermediates, to help subsequent authors (e.g. `static auto const sq = [](auto x) { return x*x; };` and `auto const a1 = sq(L1 + length) + sq(L3) - sq(L2);`.

Comment: Adding `const` would be fine, if your coding style requires it. Adding `static` would be a no-op (if the compiler sees through it, which it will) or else a pessimization (if the compiler fails to see through it and thus generates code for a thread-safe initialization).

Comment: @KjMag: In the final code above, every `auto` means `double`, except for the two that mean "unnamed closure type" (lambda). I don't think changing `auto` to `double` would help; but I don't think it would hurt either.

Comment: @KjMag not at all. Most code I see today embraces the Almost Always Auto philosophy and even uses the trailing return type layout (e.g. `auto length_angle(double length) -> double`).

Comment: @Snowhawk04 I was referring to the variables declarations, not functions.

Comment: @Quuxplusone What I meant was it's harder to spot the error if you use auto - sometimes you use functions returning doubles, but you want to have it rounded to int in the end - if you declare the variable type explicitly, you show that you want int, not double. If you don't do it explicitly, it's harder to realise afterwards that you've got double where you wanted an int, and when you do realise it, it's harder to locate where exactly the error was made and where the double should stop being double if all the intermediate variables are auto.

Answer (score 5):

Only one small thing to add. The last thing you're doing is converting from radians to degrees. You should write an inline function for that:

```
double radiansToDegrees(const double radians)
{
    return radians * (180.0 / M_PI);
}
```

This makes it more clear that:

1. The last part of the equation is just a units conversion and not a part of the formula
2. The result is in a particular unit

Just last week I found code that was acting very strangely and it turned out to be an issue with conversion between radians and degrees. This is something that programmers get wrong all the time! I recommend renaming the variables to indicate that they are working in radians and the function name to reflect that it returns a value in degrees.

Comment: I would parenthesize `(180 / M_PI)` so that it can be evaluated at compile time.

Comment: Good point! Added.

Answer (score 3):

As the same expressions (powers)  are calculated multiple times I would extract the values and look for meaningful names. And as the power are squares I wound avoid `pow` function calls:

```
double sum1 = constlength_link1 + length;
double sq1 = sum1 * sum1;
double sqE = length_base_end * length_base_end;
double sq2 = length_link2 * length_link2;
```

and then

```
theta1 = theta0 - (acos((sq1 + (sqE - sq2)) / (2. * length_base_end * sum1))) * 180. / M_PI;

theta2 = 180. - (acos((sq1 - (sqE - sq2)) / (2. * length_link2 * sum1))) * 180. / M_PI;
```